# How add it in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I found a solution to one of my problem which is to add following to maven pom.xml:

```
javax.ws.rs*;version="[1,2)",   
javax.servlet*;version="2.5",
javax.xml.bind*;version="[2.1,3)",
*;version="0";resolution:=optional
&lt;/Import-Package&gt;
```

Where should I add it? In which brackets?
Consider following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lalala</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>lalala</name>
    <description>lalala</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>

                    ...

                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                       ...

                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

</project>
```

It will solve a problem with my atlassian jira plugin and I don't know where to put it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Which is the `jar` package in your solution? If you know the `jar` info, just add it into `dependencies` node in `pom.xml`

Comment: That seems to be an `instruction` for http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html plugin. How sure are you about that these lines would really solve anything for you?

Comment: it is an instructor to attlasian plugin. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to add them to pom.xml as all these packages are standard Java API packages. They are already added to your classpath by Java.